# Change UIImage's height in UITableViewCell according to it's position to UITableView's center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, height

I need to achieve behavior similar to UIPickerView, but with UITableView. To increase the height of cell's UIImageView if this cell in the center of the UITableView depending on scroll.

I can detect scroll of UITableView in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

In this method I can get the center of UITableView

```
CGFloat center = self.view.frame.size.height/2.0f;
```

I can get the position of the visible cells and their middle points:

```
NSArray *paths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
    CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cellRect = CGRectOffset(cellRect, -self.horizontalTableView2.contentOffset.x, -self.horizontalTableView2.contentOffset.y);
    CGFloat y = CGRectGetMidY(cellRect);
    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    CGRect frame = cell.paramImage.frame;
    frame.size.height = ???;
    cell.paramImage.frame = frame;
}
```

How to calculate height depending on how far cell is positioned from the center of my UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my sample [project](https://github.com/Blyabtroi/HorizontalTableView) with horizontal UITableView which resize images in UITableViewCell while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can get cell.frame in self.view like this.

```
CGRect rect  = [cell.superView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
```

Then you can calculate how far cell is positioned from the center of my UITableView.

Comment: double fabs(cell.frame.center.y - self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0f);